How to set Linux directory permission for writers?
I have an directory called Videos , and its permission is 3775, owned by triplez:writers.
drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
drwxrwxrwx root    root    usbhdd
drwxrwsr-t triplez writers Videos

When the download program aria2(startup by root) download files to this directory, the new directory's permission changed to drwxr-sr-x root:writers, which other users in writers group can't delete them.
I have tested root account to create file/directory, it appears the same behavior.
root@homelab-nas:/usbhdd/Videos# mkdir test
root@homelab-nas:/usbhdd/Videos# namei -l `pwd`/test
f: /usbhdd/Videos/test
drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
drwxrwxrwx root    root    usbhdd
drwxrwsr-t triplez writers Videos
drwxr-sr-x root    writers test
root@homelab-nas:/usbhdd/Videos# touch filetest
root@homelab-nas:/usbhdd/Videos# namei -l `pwd`/filetest
f: /usbhdd/Videos/filetest
drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
drwxrwxrwx root    root    usbhdd
drwxrwsr-t triplez writers Videos
-rw-r--r-- root    writers filetest

I wonder how to change /usbhdd/Videos directory's permission that make every new directory or file under this directory can be read & write from writers user group?

The permission of the parent directory isn't really relevant. umask is.

@TomYan I don't understand this much, using the umask would only narrow the permission. How can I achieve that root writes a file under the target directory and writers has the permission to read/write?

@TripleZ, @TomYan means that you are already narrowing the permission because your umask for root is something like 0022. Try making it 0002 for the process that creates these files and directories.

@nickie so the umask is a global option for an user's shell session. Is I should set umask 0002 for root user?

@TripleZ, I wrote this as an answer, as it's becoming too long for a comment.

As @TomYan wrote in his comment, umask is what matters here. The default value is usually 0022, which gives permission 755 (or rwxr-xr-x) to new directories and permission 644 (or rw-r--r--) to new regular files.

I don't understand this much, using the umask would only narrow the permission. How can I achieve that root writes a file under the target directory and writers has the permission to read/write?
– TripleZ

You are already narrowing the permission because your umask for root is something like 0022. Try making it 0002 for the process that creates these files and directories.

So the umask is a global option for a user's shell session. Should I set umask 0002 for root user?
– TripleZ

Yes, umask is sort-of a "global option". It's not only for a user's shell session; it can have a different value for each and any user process (including a shell session, of course). Read the documentation: umask(1p) or umask(2), or read e.g., this, to understand how exactly umask works.
I would not recommend setting it to 0002 for the root user, as this would imply that all files and directories created by root would be group-writable. This would be a bad idea, security-wise. I suggest setting it just for the process that runs your software.
Assuming that your software is this aria2, I understand it's a command line utility, starting child processes by forking when necessary. You can set umask just for the process running this. Forked processes will inherit the umask.
$ (umask 0002 && aria2c http://example.org/mylinux.iso)

See here for more on how to set the umask just for one command.

Thanks for your answer, I get the main idea. And my aria2 is in docker :lol:
